# What Does "Error: Variable is used unitialized Whenever "if" Condition is False" mean?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working through a problem set, and I've encountered an issue when creating a function and returning its value. The code is below:

```
int shift(char c){
    int key;
    if (isupper(c)){
        key = c - 65;
    }else if (islower(c)){
        key = c - 97;
    }
return key;
}
```

The function takes a character as its input and returns an integer. That integer value will be the alphabetic character minus specific ascii values that will set each alphabetic number in order from 0 to 25. The problem arises when I do not initialize the key variable. When I do initialize it equal 0, the function works as it should.

What I would like to know is why that is occurring? I do not see how leaving key unitialized should affect its value after the calculation is completed.

The actual error that comes up is:

```
vigenere.c:48:15: error: variable 'key' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition
      is false [-Werror,-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
    }else if (islower(c)){
```

Comment: Think about what `key` is if both `if` conditions are false.

Comment: If `c` is neither upper, nor lower, then `key` will not have received a value.

Comment: Anything that is not a letter will be neither uppercase nor lowercase. Then you have an uninitialised variable and hence undefined behaviour. Always initialise variables (unless you are an expert with some performance-critical reason not to). Anyway, why even have a variable here? Just `return` the value without an intermediate variable. Then nothing can be uninitialised. If anyone told you that multiple `return` points are bad, discard their advice.

Comment: There is no "calculation completed" if you don't enter any `if` body.

Comment: @underscore_d I removed the variable key and changed where it says key = to simply say return. Then I added a return 0; to the end, and it still works. Thank yo ufor your advice.

I realize now that the key variable is pointless in that function because in the main function, I use that very same variable there. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this warning because there are code paths where `key` is not set and subsequently used.

The `isupper` and `islower` functions are not opposites, e.g. a false return value from one doesn't imply a true return value from the other.  For example, `c` contains the character `'0'`, both `isupper` and `islower` will return false.  When that happens, the value of `key` is never set and so its value is **indeterminate**.  This means that its value can't be reliably predicted, and attempting to read it can in fact invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to handle the case where both functions return false:

```
int shift(char c){
    int key;
    if (isupper(c)){
        key = c - 65;
    }else if (islower(c)){
        key = c - 97;
    } else {
        key = c;
    }
    return key;
}
```

Or alternaltely:

```
int shift(char c){
    if (isupper(c)){
        return c - 65;
    }else if (islower(c)){
        return c - 97;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see now that I was not account for all possibilities. I forgot to think about what would happen if neither if condition was met. Thank you!